# Getting an import error on python cv2 library

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, anaconda, anaconda3

I am working on project and I am using the conda environment file to setup my virtual environment.

you can see the environment file content here:

```
name: testenv

channels:
- pytorch
- menpo
- defaults
dependencies:
- jupyter
- matplotlib
- python=3.5
- parso=0.7
- scikit-learn
- scipy
- opencv3
- vlfeat
- pytorch-cpu
- torchvision-cpu
- pip
- pip:
  - visdom
- pyyaml
```

I successfully setup the conda environment but while executing the first import cell on jupyter notebook; I have getting this error. You guys can see the error and code as well.

If it helps, I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS version.

This is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib notebook
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from utils import *
from student_feature_matching import match_features
from student_sift import get_features
from student_harris import get_interest_points
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
```

The error I am getting:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-60a8c5f229f9> in <module>()
      3 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'autoreload')
      4 get_ipython().run_line_magic('autoreload', '2')
----> 5 import cv2
      6 import numpy as np
      7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_memdup2
```

I have no idea what is this and how to solve this. Can anybody know why this error is causing and what the solution to it?

Comment: Please post your code (only the relevant, minimal code that leads to the error) and the full error traceback as text, not as an image. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AlexK I edited my question with the minimal code that produce the error as you asked. Hope you can help me with it now.

Comment: Searching the internet for `g_memdup2`, it appears it's associated with [glib](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=264759). You may need to [install](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/glib) it and/or update your conda environment (by running `conda update`).